# Unlist the two lists (output of a function) in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function

I am trying to run a function in R called `dataQuality`. The output of that function is two lists containing data frames. This is a simplification of the code:

```
dataQuality <- function(x){
    results <- list(listDF_WY,listDF_CY)
    return(results)
}

data <- dataQuality(x = Streamflow)
```

and the output is:

[image]

How is possible to unlist the two output lists of the function?

I want to have a separate list with the 31 dataframes (`listDF_WY`) and another list with the other dataframes (`listDF_CY`). The expected output is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you using `unlist`? What is the expected result?

Comment: `listDF_WY <- data[[1]]`?

Comment: From the online help:  "Given a list structure x, unlist simplifies it to produce a vector which contains all the atomic components which occur in x."  So `unlist` converts a list to a vector.  But you say you want two lists.  That's contradictory.

Comment: Yes, the answer is ```listDF_WY <- data[[1]]```. Thank you Roland!